# Codeigniter headers on redirect

Tags: codeigniter, redirect

This is driving me a little crazy. In codeignter I am redirecting after submitting forms or completing actions. Every time I do so, it producing what looks like server check headers.

```
0HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 24 May 2013 21:35:39 GMT Content-Type: text/html 
Content-Length: 5997 Connection: keep-alive Server: Apache/2 X-Powered-By:
PHP/5.3.13
```

My URL helper is loaded and it is redirecting, but I really don't want to user to be able to see this every single time they try to go to another page.

Initially, I was just using a regular redirect, like this

```
redirect ('/home/);
```

But that was giving me a found error, so based on some research and a few suggestions I added the refresh, like this

```
redirect('/home/', 'refresh');
```

and I believe it's the refresh that is causing that header, but otherwise I receave a found error even though it is redirecting to the page I want.

I did also try a location, like this

```
redirect('/home/', 'location');
```

but I'm getting that found error again.

Help please!

Edit: my .htaccess file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


# Begin password protection #
AuthName "Password Protected"
Require valid-user
AuthUserFile "*****"
AuthType basic
# End password protection #
```

Comment: What specifically is the "found error"?

Comment: The exact message is.

0
Found
The document has moved here.

Additionally, a 302 Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Fri, 24 May 2013 22:59:27 GMT Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 14814 Connection: keep-alive Server: Apache/2 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.13

Comment: did you try like `redirect ('home');` and if it doesn't work then give your htaccess file

Comment: I did, it still gives me the found error. I don't really have anything pertaining to links in my htaccess...just code that removes the /index/ in the url and password protection. I'll put it up in my post though

Comment: Do you get an error if you just go that URL in your browser? I would also try using just php: `header('Location: /home');` then you'd know if it's CodeIgniter specific or not.

Comment: If I go to the page directly, I don't get the error....it's just when I redirect. And yes, I did still get the found error when I used just the header Location.

Comment: That is really strange. Next I'd try commenting out what is in .htaccess and see if that changes anything, then open `/application/config/routes.php` and try commenting out everything except `$route["default_controller"] = "home";` and see if that has any effect. Could you post a URL here to a page where the error is occurring?

Comment: I commented out everything in the .htaccess file and nothing changed....and the only thing I have in my routes is the default controller. I've done this a zillion times with the same settings and never run into this before...I wonder if I'm just going crazy? haha

Comment: I'm working on http://writeyourfiction.com Since it's not a public site yet the temporary username is username and the password is password

Comment: It mainly happens after you register if you click on the logo in the upper right corner.

Comment: After I filled out the register form and hit submit, I got a 500 server error. Then I hit refresh and got a 310 redirect loop error. I logged in via another browser and upon logging in, was stuck in the same redirect loop.

Comment: what? what is going on? I haven't seen that before.... What the hell...

Comment: thank you for all your help....it looks like I'm going to strip my whole site and try and build it back up again. Something really wrong is going on....there goes two weeks haha